# Concatenating new values to a particular cell of cell

Tags: matlab, cell

I have cell of cell with name `TEMP(1x4)`. Each cell of cell has `TEMP{1}` to `Temp{4}` different set of values. Eg.

```
TEMP{1} =1:10  
TEMP{2} =1:20 
TEMP{3} =1:30
...
```

Now I have created a new cell lets name `NEWTEMP={ 11 , 12, 13}`. I want to concatenate `NEWTEMP` values with `TEMP{1}` such that now `TEMP{1}= 1:13`. How can I do it easily.

I need `TEMP{1}` and `NEWTEMP` values to be concatenated in a single cell (i.e. in `TEMP{1}`)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
temp = cell(4,1);
for i = 1:4
    temp{i} = 1:i*10;
end

newtemp = {};
newtemp{1} = 11:13;

temp{1} = [temp{1} newtemp{1}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do

```
NEWTEMP = {[11,12,13]}
```

not

```
NEWTEMP = {11,12,13}
```

Look carefully at the difference between the two, the first is a 1x1 cell array containing a 1x3 numeric array

The second is a 1x3 cell array containing a 3 1x1 numeric arrays

If you use the first example, then concatenation is completed like this:

```
TEMP{1} = [TEMP{1} cell2mat(NEWTEMP)]
```